# Contact card not always appearing

Tags: list, outlook, office, contacts, mysite

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site which includes a list. This list contains a column called 'Called By' and this column is of type 'Person or Group'.

When this list is viewed on my PC (Windows XP with Internet Explorer 8), the user can hover the mouse over an entry in this column and a 'contact card' appears that displays information presumably from MySite.

However, when my colleague views the list on their PC (also Windows XP with Internet Explorer 8), hovering the mouse over an entry in this column does nothing but highlight the name as a link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are they logged in to Office Communicator / Lync? That is a prerequisite for this card to appear (it is not a SharePoint card actually, but a little program started via an Active X control)